# How do I generate a random list in Python with duplicates numbers

Tags: python, list

So I just started programming in Python a few days ago. And now, im trying to make a program that generates a random list, and then, choose the duplicates elements. The problem is, I dont have duplicate numbers in my list.

This is my code:

```
import random

def generar_listas (numeros, rango):
    lista = [random.sample(range(numeros), rango)]
    print("\n", lista, sep="")
    return
def texto_1 ():
    texto = "Debes de establecer unos parámetros para generar dos listas aleatorias"
    print(texto)
    return

texto_1()
generar_listas(int(input("\nNumero maximo: ")), int(input("Longitud: ")))
```

And for example, I choose 20 and 20 for random.sample, it generates me a list from 0 to 20 but in random position. I want a list with random numbers and duplicated.

Comment: You could sample from a container that has duplicates.  Assuming python2.x:  `random.sample(range(20) + range(20), 20)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want is fairly simple. You want to generate a random list of numbers that contain some duplicates. The way to do that is easy if you use something like numpy.

- Generate a list (range) of 0 to 10.
- Sample randomly (with replacement) from that list.

**Like this:**

```
import numpy as np
print np.random.choice(10, 10, replace=True)
```

**Result:**

```
[5 4 8 7 0 8 7 3 0 0]
```

If you want the list to be ordered just use the builtin function "sorted(list)"

```
sorted([5 4 8 7 0 8 7 3 0 0])
[0 0 0 3 4 5 7 7 8 8]
```

If you don't want to use numpy you can use the following:

```
print [random.choice(range(10)) for i in range(10)]
[7, 3, 7, 4, 8, 0, 4, 0, 3, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Its no possible do it with random module?

Comment: Thank you very much. citaret answer works too but I will choose this one because you mention numpy.

Comment: No problem @Eduard

Answer (score 2):

random.randrange is what you want.

```
>>> [random.randrange(10) for i in range(5)]
[3, 2, 2, 5, 7]
```