# Remove specific consecutive duplicate in a list

Tags: python, duplicates, python-itertools

The post is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511555/fast-remove-consecutive-duplicates-python) but what I want, is to remove specific consecutive duplicate in a list.
So let's say we have this list:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,3,2,4,4,4,1]
```

I want to have:

```
[1,2,2,3,2,4,4,4,1]
```

I want to remove only the "ones". I am trying `itertools.groupby` but I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: What’s the logic? Do you want to remove all duplicate ones? All duplicate ones at the beginning of the string? All duplicates at the beginning of the string regardless of value?

Comment: Ultimately it's very similar to the solution in the duplicate; use `groupby`, which returns tuples likes `(1, (1, 1, 1))`, you just need to decide whether you'll use the first item or the second item depending on whether it's `1` or not…

Comment: The pattern is: Whereever there is duplicate "1" should be removed.
Another example:
from
[1,1,1,2,2,3,2,1,1,4,4,4,1,1,1,1]
to
[1,2,2,3,2,1,4,4,4,1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and use the grouping key to either keep the key or keep the returned group:

```
l = [1,1,1,2,2,3,2,4,4,4,1]

from itertools import chain, groupby

list(chain.from_iterable([k] if k==1 else v for k,v in groupby(l)))
# [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Nice one , one more similar approach `sum([[1] if i==1 else list(j) for i,j in groupby(a)],[])`

Comment: Note that flattening with sum is not really recommended though @Nagakiran , it has higher complexity than necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you search for ones at the beginning of the list, you do not need to import a module to do this, it is also possible to iterate over the elements in a for-loop:

```
your_list = [1,1,1,2,2,3,2,4,4,4,1]
for index, element in enumerate(your_list):
    if element != 1:
        break
if index:
    result = your_list[index-1:]
else:
    result = your_list
```

This would check for ones, until it finds another number. The index of the other number -1 is meant to be the beginning of the list.

If there is no 1 in the list, `index` will be zero and the original list is returned.

Comment: Note that this assumes the searched-for value is at the beginning of the list, and it assumes only the first occurence should be de-duplicated (this requirement is unclear)…

Comment: Oh, thanks, I assumed that and will edit my answer