# random to produce duplicated elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

When working with random module

```
In [1]: from random import *                                                                                                  

In [2]: sample([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], k=4)                                                                                     
Out[2]: [20, 30, 50, 10]
```

the result is not randomly completely

How could produce a result as

```
In [2]: sample([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], k=4)                                                                                     
Out[2]: [20, 20, 20, 10]
```

to generate duplicated elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379515/how-do-i-generate-a-random-list-in-python-with-duplicates-numbers Here you go, your question is answered already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sample` is the wrong tool, as you've seen. Instead, you could use [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
choices([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], k=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use Python's standard `random.choices` where you can specify optional weights for each element you generate. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```py
choices([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], weights=[5, 50, 10, 15, 10], k=4)
```

Output

```
[40, 20, 50, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

```
import numpy as np

x = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

print(np.random.choice(x, 4, replace=True))
```

Output:

```
[50 50 30 30]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `random.choices` - *New in Python version 3.6*. - The function definition is below; and you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices).

```
random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
```

You can assign `weights` in order to give a specific element precedence over others. - Although I believe the example below would satisfy your needs.

**Example**

```
import random

random.choices([1, 2, 3, 4], k=4)
```

Alternatively in older Python versions you can use `random.choice` as shown below; although it simply support one argument, a sequence.

**Example**

```
import random

population = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def choices(population, k=1):
    return [random.choice(population) for _ in range(k)] if k > 1 else random.choice(population)

choices(population, k=5)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 4, 2, 5, 1]
```